# Is it faster to do string/date comparisons, or to insert-replace in the database?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

### Problem

I have a database (SQLite or MySQL) full of rainfall values for every day in the last few years. It is very simple:

```
 date          | rain
------------------------
"2014-10-20"     3.3
```

Each day, I pull in a CSV file from my local meteorology bureau. They only publish CSV files with the entire year's data, no daily/weekly/etc files, so by the end of the year there are 365 rows in the file. Within each row the date is split up into the Year, Month, and Day fields.

So when it comes time to store the info in the database, I have two options.

### Solution 1: Do date comparison

I would save the date at which I last ran the program, in either the database or a text file. I parse that date using `Date.strptime` and store it as `last_run_time`. Then I load the CSV file with `CSV.read('raindata.csv').each do |row|`, and for every row, I parse the three date fields as a new Date object with `rowdate = Date.strptime("#row[2]}-#{row[3]}-#{row[4]}")` and say `if rowdate > last_run_time then` insert info into database.

This way, I avoid making database calls to insert-or-replace values I already have. By the end of the year this spares me 364 database queries, but it means I do a lot of Date parsing and comparing.

### Solution 2: Just let the database handle it

I would avoid all of that, and just say *for each row in the CSV, insert or ignore into the database*. The date field in the DB is unique so if I try to insert but already have the date, it just ignores the query. Pro: avoid making Date comparisons and parsing, con: as many as 364 unnecessary hits to the database.

### Question

Which of these two solutions is the smarter, more efficient, more resource-friendly one? Is it better to make unnecessary database queries and spare the CPU, or vice verca?

Comment: How much programming time are you willing to sacrifice in order to save 0.1 s of CPU time?

Answer (score -1):

Database Handles are the most heavy operations whichever solution has lesser number of query is the best approach.

Parsing and Language function have much much much lesser complexity.. so process inputs in language and lesser queries

Answer (score -1):

Hitting the database is probably 1,000 or 1,000,000 times more expansive than comparing dates. Having said that, it makes no difference because making 364 hits to the database once a day is considered zero load for any practical purposes.

If you need your update script to run as fast as possible, do date comparisons. You take the risk that there will be some bugs and maybe some data will be missed sometime in the future.

If you have the extra few seconds, and you care most about data integrity and simplicity update the whole thing daily.